# Show popover in webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I am using web grid to show data in mvc application, I want to show a popover when hover a column in each row of webgrid, I need to show content by passing value to controller and show in popover, Is it possible to do this using bootstrap popover?
or using any other popover?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jquery. use a tooltip.js and call it every column selection function.